# Is it possible to configure tomcat to use an external directory under eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat

instead of:   `c:\bin\tomcat8\webapps`
I want webapps (or at least webapps/DirectoryName) to be:

`c:\Users\Name\git\Directoryname`

I know on Mac we can do this with a symbolic link

> ln -s /Users/Name/git/Directoryname/.. /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/DirectoryName

How can we do this in a Windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried created a symbolic link: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin: http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html

- Starting and stopping Tomcat 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x
- Registering Tomcat process to Eclipse debugger
- Creating a WAR project (wizard can update server.xml file)
- Adding Java Projects to Tomcat classpath
- Setting Tomcat JVM parameters, classpath and bootclasspath
- Exporting a Tomcat project to a WAR File
- Capability to use a custom Tomcat classloader to load classes in several java projects at the same classloader level than classes in a Tomcat project

We've been successfully using this plugin several years.